# why isnt "stack[top--] ;" a valid statement

Tags: java, arrays

I have pointed to the line with an arrow mark.
The Java compiler says this expression isn't valid. Why?

I'm a beginner at java, thanks in advance :)

```
class stack {

    stack(int size) {
        private int top = -1;
        private int stck[] = new int[size];
    }

    void push(int item) {

        if (top == stck.length - 1)

            System.out.println("StackFull");
        else
            stck[++top] = item;
    }

    int pop ()
        {   
            if (top == -1) System.out.println("StackEmpty");
            else
                 stck[top--] ; <<========= Java Compiler says this expression isnt valid why ?
        }

    void Display() {
        for (int x : stck) {
            System.out.println(x);
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't declared `top` member variable properly, you did it in constructor, but it should be in the class scope:

```
class Stack {
    private int top = -1 ;
    private int stck[];

    // constructor
    public Stack(int size) {
        stck = new int[size];
    }
}
```

If you declare variable in the class constructor it will be just local variable and will not be visible to the rest of the methods

Comment: `size` is passed to the constructor...:)

Comment: This is not the only issue

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera: you are right, I see you described the second issue, so I don't repeat

Answer (score 0):

This is not a issue with `stck[top--] ;`. You need to introduce a variable here else it is not a valid `Java` statement

Like

```
int a=stck[top--];
```

Not only here But also you will have error in following too

```
int[] arr=new int[5];
arr[2]; // not a valid statement
```

You need to assign it to variable

```
int ex=arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

```
class Stack {
    private int top = -1 ;
    private int stck[] = new int[SIZE] ;

    public Stack() {
    }
}
```

Problem 2:

```
int poppedItem = stck[top--];
```

Answer (score 0):

`stck[top--] ;` simply accesses an array element - it doesn't do anything with it. This isn't allowed in Java, because it usually means you forgot to do something with the value.

In this case, I'm guessing you wanted to:

```
return stck[top--];
```

However, you also need to handle the "stack empty" case properly. You still need to exit the method; I'd suggest you should do so by throwing an exception in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that `stck` and `top` need to be fields rather than local variables (as explained in other answers), another problem is that the `pop` method is declared to return `int`, but it's possible (in fact certain) for the method body to "complete normally" without an explicit `return` or `throw`. This isn't allowed for non-void methods. You need to explicitly `return` the value you pop off the stack, and the failure case should probably throw an exception instead of just printing a message.

```
int pop() {
  if(top == -1) {
    throw new EmptyStackException();
  }
  else {
    return stck[top--];
  }
}
```

Likewise, it would be more idiomatic java to have `push` throw an exception when the stack is full, rather than failing silently.